# Can't use CTRL+K on Stack Overflow in Chrome

Tags: support, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> is a Chrome shortcut which puts a `?` into the address bar, so I can't use it to indent the code. How do I remove/block it as a Chrome shortcut?

Comment: What?  I'm able to do it below and it works just fine in an answer.  I wouldn't guarantee any good behavior for comment boxes, though.

Comment: But whenever I press CTRL-K, it doesnt work, but it used to.. must be something to do with an update.. [link](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en), here you can see `CTRL-K` as an address bar shortcut.

Comment: Works fine for me, so long as I'm in a post. I suggest you specify your exact browser details (version, OS etc) in the question.

Comment: Windows 10, Google Chrome Version 48.0.2564.109 m. Also, funnily enough, it works fine in other StackExchange sites except SO. On SO, it works randomly sometimes, but more often, it does not.

Answer (score 4):

[According to **Glen Murphy, Design Director, Google Chrome**](https://www.quora.com/In-Chrome-for-Windows-typing-ctrl-k-brings-up-enter-query-and-a-In-the-address-bar-Whats-the-purpose-of-this-I-dont-see-any-difference-in-search-results-with-or-without-the)

> It's there for backwards compatibility with the search shortcut in
>   previous browsers. The question mark is a way to force a search (for
>   cases where your query looks a lot like a URL).

The Stack Overflow <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> shortcut works in Chrome if you are editing a post. Otherwise, it is going to behave like a normal Chrome shortcut.